# Editable DropDown List via Validation

Tags: c#, excel, validation

I have a quite simple question - but I don't get any further with it.

I want to provide suggestions in my via Validation generated DropDown-List - but also let the user the freedom to edit to DropDown-List without any Error.

This is my Code:

```
else if (SpaltenBeschreibung.Ueberschrift.Equals("Land"))
{             
   range.Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, String.Join(";", ListeLaender.ToArray()), Type.Missing);
   range.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
   range.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;                   
   continue;
}
```

I tried and googled a lot - but i don't get the right settings to allow user edit and also show the "Liste.Laender"-List in the DropDown.

Any suggestions?

Here is a discription of whatI want, but with the wrong code... http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Excel-In-Cell-DropDown-with-CSharp.aspx

"Error Alert defines the message that should show up when an invalid value is entered – and allows to disable the Error Alert if need be. So if all you wanted was a DropDown with “suggested” choices, you could just disable the error alert, and you would have a cell with a DropDown, where users could still type any freeform text they please."

That doesn't help me :(

Comment: How exactly to you expect to *validate* the input when the user has the "freedom" to enter any value they want?

Comment: It is possible, Excel has an option for that... i can uncheck the alert under "Data" | "Datavalidation" | "Alerts" (Freely translated from german).

Comment: Where is this code inside, how are you triggering it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 
`range.Validation.ShowError = false` 
No errors are going to be shown regarding that cell, if you are sure that whats you want

Answer (score 0):

Consider using **3** cells:

Put the DV dropdown in cell **A1.**

Leave **A2** empty.

In **A3** enter:

```
=IF(A2="",A1,A2)
```

Thus if the user wants to override the DV, they enter a value in **A2**

Comment: I don't use any cells - i use an list for that. When I add an empty space to my list (LaenderListe.Add(" ");) it is not shown in the DropDown-List.
I changed range.Validation.IgnoreBlank to false of course...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by Changing the xlAlertStyle to "Warning" or "Information" (i'm not quite sure and i don't have my sourcecode here to look it up). This allows it to change the cell even is the validation rules are on after a user prompt ;)